# Java Regex to find substring

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have following string "Class (102) (401)" and "Class (401)" i want to find regex to find substring which always return me last bracket value in my case it is '(401) '

Following is my code

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*(\\(\\d+\\))");
    Matcher mat = MY_PATTERN.matcher("Class (102) (401)");
    while (mat.find()){
        System.out.println(mat.group());
    }
```

It is returning

--(
--)
--(
--)

Comment: How about getting the index of the last ( and ) and getting the substring between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*(\\(\\d+\\))");
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/ti286)

Comment: i tried and it returns "Class (102) (401)" i want only last value which is in last bracket '401'

Comment: @Faisalkhan: You need to use `group(1)`. See the working link.

Comment: one more small help if i want 401 instead (401) then what will be the change ?

Comment: @Faisalkhan: Use the pattern: `".*\\((\\d+)\\)"`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
(?<=\()[^\)(]+(?=\)[^\)\(]+$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
(?<=\()[^\)(]+(?=\)[^\)\(]+$)

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks; free-spacing

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=\()»
   Match the character “(” literally «\(»
Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^\)(]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   A ) character «\)»
   The character “(” «(»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=\)[^\)\(]+$)»
   Match the character “)” literally «\)»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^\)\(]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A ) character «\)»
      A ( character «\(»
   Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

how about the expression: `.*\\(([^\\(\\)]+)\\)[^\\(\\)]*$`

it finds a `(` followed by non-brackets `[^\\(\\)]` (your desired string) followed by a `)` and after that are only non-brackets allowed, so it must be the last